# C++ return type T(&)[] vs using reference = T(&)[] as return type

Tags: c++, reference

I'm using

```
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.59)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

and in the following code operator[] compiles but bar does not.

```
template<typename T>
class foo {
private:
        std::vector<T> data {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

public:
        using reference = T(&)[];

        reference operator[](std::size_t n) { return *static_cast<T(*)[]>(static_cast<void*>(&data[2 * n])); }
        T(&)[] bar(std::size_t n) { return *static_cast<T(*)[]>(static_cast<void*>(&data[2 * n])); }

};
```

with error

```
test.cpp:15:5: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
        T(&)[] bar(std::size_t n) { return *static_cast<T(*)[]>(static_cast<void*>(&data[2 * n])); }
        ~  ^
```

Shouldn't these be equivalent? It seems the compiler doesn't recognize T(&)[] as a type when used as a declaration specifier.

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is wrong. Square brackets of an array come after the name in C++. For example if you declare an array variable:

```
extern int arr[]; // yes
extern int[] arr; // no
```

Same applies to functions with array return type. The square brackets come after the name of the function. Note that argument list is always immediately after the name, therefore the brackets are after the argument list.

Furthermore, for the reference to apply to the array rather than its elements, the name must be within the parentheses surrounding the ampersand. For example when declaring a variable:

```
extern int (&arr)[]; // reference to array
extern int &arr[];   // syntactically, array of references
                     // however those are not allowed
```

When we combine these, the correct syntax to return reference to an array:

```
T (&bar(std::size_t n))[]
```

---

This is quite ugly, so I recommend using a type alias like you used with the operator overload. But I also recommend against giving reference the alias (except when it is used for generic programming such as in containers and iterators). Instead, My suggestion is:

```
using Arr = T[];
Arr& bar(int n);
```

Or, use trailing return type as demonstrated by [cigien](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61957463/2079303).

---

P.S. Don't static_cast through `void*`. Idiomatic way is to use reinterpret_cast:

```
*reinterpret_cast<T(*)[]>(&data[2 * n]);
```

P.P.S. I'm not sure if your trick has well defined behaviour when indirecting through the resulting pointer. At the very least, it is unconventional. I also don't see any advantages over simply returning a pointer to an element instead:

```
T* bar(std::size_t n) { return &data[2*n]; }
```

Comment: I like the detailed explanation of why the syntax is actually wrong, and how to reach the correct syntax. +1

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explication. This is a minimal example, the use case is an iterator over chunked pixel data, we don't know the number of channels at compile time, in the practical example the 2 in the index is actually a variable for the number of channels and the caller is expecting a ref to a T[] where the array is over the number of channels, the index will let them get each channel of the pixel. 

Since it's an iterator I believe a reference type is expected, and the using reference = ...  is actually from providing the name expected for the type trait.

Comment: @MichaelConlen `using reference = T*;` might work. I recommend trying it out. It does have the limitation that `&*it` won't work (which would result in pointer to array of unspecified length with your approach, but would be ill-formed with mine).

Answer (score 1):

Those two declarations are equivalent conceptually, it's just that the compiler doesn't recognize that particular syntax at that position in the function declaration.

It will work if you use a trailing-return-type:

```
auto bar(std::size_t n) -> T(&)[] {   // <- like this
  return *static_cast<T(*)[]>(static_cast<void*>(&data[2 * n])); 
}
```

Or the less readable (IMO) declaration syntax:

```
T (&bar(std::size_t n)) [] {  // <- like this
  return *static_cast<T(*)[]>(static_cast<void*>(&data[2 * n])); 
}
```